# App Development for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

Is there a unified way of developing app that works on both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.

What I mean is that, can I make a single solution/project base or do I need to create different solutions, and then apply code sharing strategies to minimize the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need separate projects for the two app platforms, but you can share a lot of the effort by utilising portable class libraries, especially if you are using the MVVM pattern.  For example, you can make a shared view model class using the PCL version of MVVMLight.

Comment: If everything is supposed to run on a .NET CLR, then why can't we have a single solution that runs on all types of OS flavors(Windows 8 Pro, Windows 8 Rt, Windows 8 phone). Did microsoft miss anything here ?

Comment: You'd have to ask them that!  Things are getting better with Portable Class Libraries, but there will still be a lot of difference in the actual UI itself.  A layout that makes sense on a tablet is unlikely to make sense on a phone, and vice-versa.